# How can I check the parity of a DES key?

Tags: c, cryptography, des

I am working on the DES (Data Encryption Standard) algorithm in my Cryptography class, as a part of which I have to write a C code which includes a function to check the parity of a DES key.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do a [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=DES+parity), and pick [one of the first results that comes up](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2005/09/08/des-key-parity/).

Taken from the above link:

```
bool AdjustDESKeyParity(UCHAR* pucKey, int nKeyLen)
{
   int cPar;
   for(int i = 0; i < nKeyLen; i++)
   {
      cPar = 0;
      for(int j = 0; j < DES::BLOCKSIZE; j++)
      {
         if(pucKey[i] & (0×01 << j))
            cPar = !cPar;
      }
      if(!cPar)
         pucKey[i] ^= 0×01;
   }
   return true;
}
```

This isn't pure C, but it should be easy enough to translate.

Comment: thank u very much !! The code is very much understandable to me..it's just that I wasn't getting the logic for it when I tried..will think more next time before posting such questions !!